# stm32 i2c: What is the cause for a start-stop-impulse after a successful i2c MasterTransmit-Receive on stm32?

Tags: stm32, i2c

I have i2c multi master operation. In this test there are two devices connected.

stm32f769 does a MasterTransmit followed by a MasterReceive to stm32f405 with repeated start.
stm32f405 receives data, returns it immediately and then calulates on rxed data. After that it does a MasterTransmit to the stm32f769.

At some point it seems that the stm32f405 (as a master) only generates a start-stop-impulse without sending data. Please see image [additional start-stop-impulse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO0St.png)

I wonder what can cause this behaviour and how to avoid it.

On idle stm32f769 and stm32f405 are configured as slave.

Prerequisites:

stm32f769:

```
I2C_Initialize()
{
 AttachAddressDetectHandler(&I2C_AddressDetect);
 AttachSlaveRecieveCpltHandler(&I2C_GetData);
 AttachListenCpltHandler(&I2C_StartListen);

 AttachMasterTransmitCpltHandler(&I2C_MasterReceive);
 AttachMasterReceiveCpltHandler(&I2C_ReleaseBus);
    
 I2C_StartListen(hi2c);
}
```

stm32f405:

```
I2C_Initialize()
{
 AttachAddressDetectHandler(&I2C_AddressDetect);
 AttachSlaveRecieveCpltHandler(&I2C_GetData);
 AttachListenCpltHandler(&I2C_StartListen);
 AttachMasterTransmitCpltHandler(&I2C_ReleaseBus);
 I2C_StartListen(hi2c);
}
```

The Attach*-functions go directly into the STM32HAL.

---

stm32f769 master action:
I2C_MasterTransmit is called to start transfer of data.
I2C_MasterReceive is called by using HAL-callback on MasterTransmit is finished.

```
I2C_MasterTransmit(..)
{
 I2C_StopListen(hi2c); // disable listener
 I2C_AquireBus(hi2c);  // semaphore lock i2c
 HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Transmit_DMA(hi2c, stm32f405address, pData, size, I2C_FIRST_FRAME);
}

I2C_MasterReceive(..)
{
 HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Receive_DMA(hi2c, stm32f405address, pData, size, I2C_LAST_FRAME);
}
```

stm32f405 slave action:

The stm32f405 directly returns the received data as the master does its MasterRead. Additionally it handles the rxed data.

```
I2C_AddressDetect(..)
{
 switch (direction)
 {
  case I2C_DIRECTION_RECEIVE:
   HAL_I2C_Slave_Seq_Transmit_DMA(hi2c, rxedData, size, I2C_LAST_FRAME);
  break;
  case I2C_DIRECTION_TRANSMIT:
   HAL_I2C_Slave_Seq_Receive_DMA(hi2c, rxedData, size, I2C_FIRST_FRAME);
  break;
 }
}

I2C_GetData(..)
{
 // handle rxed data
}
```

---

The stm32f405 now starts to calculate on the received data and sends data as master to stm32f769, which is now slave.

stm32f405 master action:

```
I2C_MasterTransmit(..)
{
 I2C_StopListen(hi2c);
 I2C_AquireBus(hi2c);
 HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_DMA(hi2c, stm32f769address, pData, size);
}
```

stm32f769 slave action:

```
I2C_AddressDetect(..)
{
 HAL_I2C_DisableListen_IT(hi2c);
 switch (direction)
 {
  case I2C_DIRECTION_RECEIVE:
  break;
  case I2C_DIRECTION_TRANSMIT:
   HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive_DMA(hi2c, rxedData, size);
  break;
}

I2C_GetData(..)
{
 // handle rxed data
}
```

Comment: Cube/HAL is open source and you can/should debug it as your own code. Place "markers" (toggling a GPIO pin) at strategic positions in the code to localize the source of the start-stop sequence.